# Passing the controller value in url in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, controller

Is there any way to pass the controller value. I am loading a html page and on click of any divison, I am passing the div id in url and loading the same html page and hide all other divisions excluding the clicked one. On initial load I am using different controller and on second load of page I want to call a different controller.

Since its called at the very beginning of page load, I want to make it as variable and pass the required control. Any suggestions or alternative or inputs on this approach would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code being described?

Comment: <div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl"> here  i want to make "MainCtrl" a variable. As I am calling same html page twice referring two different controller . One on initial load and second time is when the html division element is clicked.